# Spot the PHP mySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an error on line 50 that there's an unexpected ';' in my code.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE COOL_USERS SET COUNT = COUNT + 1
                WHERE USERNAME = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($user). "'";
}
```

Line 50 is the WHERE USERNAME... line. Can anyone spot it?

Comment: i can, do i win a (prize)?

Comment: Use prepared statements and axe your linebreak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `)` in `mysqli_query`

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE COOL_USERS SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE USERNAME = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($user). "'");
}
```